# Align three code blocks in different orientations

Tags: tables, listings, subfloats, multirow

[image: Current Image]

The above image is what I can generate with -

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
...java code...
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Java source code that loads files from HDFS}
\label{fig:javaloadhdfs}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
...c code...
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{C source code that loads files from HDFS}
\label{fig:cloadhdfs}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
...bash code...
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Bash source code that loads files from HDFS}
\label{fig:bashloadhdfs}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example programs that load files from HDFS and count the number of non-whitespace characters}
\end{figure*}
```

How do I move (b) above (c), such that (a) is in the left column and (b), (c) are stacked on the right column?

I have been trying to make it a table and then use `multirow` or `subfloat` to make (a) span across two rows but I have been unsuccessful so far.

How should I approach solving this?

Comment: Please provide fully compilable code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Otherwise it is very hard to know which packages you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the two subfigures on the right within their own subfigure to get the desired layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}%left
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Fifth line
Sixth line
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}%right
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%right upper
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
First line
Second line
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%right lower
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
First line
Second line
Third line
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]